# Android 6.0 check if connected to a Wi-Fi (without Internet)

Tags: android, wifi

Here is how I check if the Android device is connected to a Wi-Fi network:

```
NetworkInfo info = ((ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context
         .CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
boolean isWifiConnected = info != null && info.isAvailable() && info.isConnected();
```

This works perfectly on all versions prior to Android 6.0.
However, on Android 6.0, if the device is connected to a Wi-Fi without Internet access, info.isConnected() returns false.

So, how can I know for sure that the device is connected to a Wi-Fi on Android 6.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Android 5.0 and above you need to use a different API to check that the device is connected to a WiFi network. The device might also be simultaneously connected to a mobile network.

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = ((ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService
                (Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
        boolean isWifiConnected = false;
        Network[] networks = connectivityManager.getAllNetworks();
        if (networks == null) {
            isWifiConnected = false;
        } else {
            for (Network network : networks) {
                NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(network);
                if (info != null && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                    if (info.isAvailable() && info.isConnected()) {
                        isWifiConnected = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return isWifiConnected;
```

Comment: I guess the caution here is that for 6.0.1 info for type wifi can be available and connected, even though it might not be authenticated and no data is getting through.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. You can check if there is an SSID, which implies a connection:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
if (wifiManager.getConnectionInfo() != null) {
    String ssid = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getSSID();
}
```

The system is routing traffic to the cell connection, so the OS is reporting the Wi-Fi network as disconnected. Android 6.0 changed the underlying routing logic to avoid Wi-Fi connections without internet. This is why `connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo()` no longer returns the `NetworkInfo` for the Wi-Fi connection w/o internet if there is an active cellular data connection.

It seems that ConnectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(Network network) is how you tell the OS to prefer one network over another.